# android Use own Image in ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have 10 graphic needs to display in my ListView

and I create a class like this

```
public class LayoutAdapterObj {
 public String addString;
 public ImageView leftImage;
 public String backgroundImageName;
 public LayoutAdapterObj(String addString,ImageView leftImageName,String backgroundImageName){
     this.addString = addString;
     this.leftImage = leftImageName;
     this.backgroundImageName = backgroundImageName;
 }
```

and when I create a LayoutAdaptor object

I do this

```
    aArray.add(new LayoutAdapterObj("1",new ImageView(null, null, R.drawable.frame1),"R.drawable.layout"));
    aArray.add(new LayoutAdapterObj("2",new ImageView(null, null, R.drawable.frame2),"R.drawable.layout"));
    LayoutListAdapter m_adapter;
    m_adapter = new LayoutListAdapter(this, R.layout.topbarlayout, aArray);
```

after that.... in my adapter class, i do this

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
                }
                LayoutAdapterObj o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {
                        TextView addText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.addtext);                     
                        ImageView leftImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.layoutframe);
                        if(!o.backgroundImageName.equals(""))
                        {

                        }
                        if(addText!=null)
                        {
                            addText.setText(o.addString);
                        }
```

the wrong message is like this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

if(leftImage != null)
{
    leftImage= o.leftImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this...example...`

```
   class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int temp;
            if(SharedVariables.is_traffic_search_ON_flag){
                temp=search_cases_trafficTicketsList.size();
            }else{
                temp=search_cases_criminalTicketsList.size();
            }
            return temp;
        }

        Activity context;

        public UserListAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, 0);

            Log.d("hh","sgbdfjfdgfk");

            this.context = context;
        }

         class ViewHolder {

             RelativeLayout rl2;
             ImageView genderimage;
             TextView ticketcounttt;
             TextView name;
             TextView city;
             TextView added_date;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){//here we inflating the layout "R.layout.cars_row"
            ViewHolder holder;
            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

                if(SharedVariables.is_traffic_search_ON_flag)rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traffic_row, null, true);
                else rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.criminal_row, null, true);

                holder = new ViewHolder();


                holder.rl2=(RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rl2); 

                try{
                holder.genderimage=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.genderimage);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                holder.ticketcounttt=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticketcounttt);
                holder.name=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.city=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.added_date=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView333);

                //Traffic cases...
                if(SharedVariables.is_traffic_search_ON_flag)
                {

                    if(search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).CaseID!=0)holder.rl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_color1); //Pink color...
                    else  holder.rl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pink_color); //Green color...

        if(search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).Sex.equals("M"))holder.genderimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.man);
                    else holder.genderimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.woman);
        holder.ticketcounttt.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.name.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.city.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.added_date.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.name.setText(search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).FirstName+" "+search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).LastName);
        holder.city.setText(search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).City+" City"+"("+search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).ZIP+")");

                    try{

                        String s[]=search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).ViolationDate.split("/");

                        String month=SharedVariables.convertFromNumberToMonth(Integer.parseInt(s[0]));
                        String day=s[1];

                        String year=s[2].substring(0,4);

                    holder.added_date.setText("Added: "+Integer.parseInt(day)+" "+month+" "+year);  
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }           

                    try{
                        holder.ticketcounttt.setText(""+search_cases_trafficTicketsList.get(position).Violations.split(",").length);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }       

                }

                //Criminal casess...
                else{

                    if(search_cases_criminalTicketsList.get(position).CaseID!=0)holder.rl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_color1); //Pink color...
                    else  holder.rl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pink_color); //Green color...

            holder.ticketcounttt.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.name.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.city.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.added_date.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
        holder.name.setText(search_cases_criminalTicketsList.get(position).FirstName+" "+search_cases_criminalTicketsList.get(position).LastName);
        holder.city.setText(search_cases_criminalTicketsList.get(position).City+" City");

                    try{

                        String s[]=search_cases_criminalTicketsList.get(position).ViolationDate.split("/");

                        String month=SharedVariables.convertFromNumberToMonth(Integer.parseInt(s[0]));
                        String day=s[1];

                        String year=s[2].substring(0,4);

                    holder.added_date.setText("Added: "+Integer.parseInt(day)+" "+month+" "+year);  
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }           

                    try{
                        holder.ticketcounttt.setText(""+search_cases_criminalTicketsList.get(position).Violations.split(",").length);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }       

                }


                rowView.setTag(holder);                 

            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            return rowView;

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }


    }`
```

call your adapter like this

UserListAdapter a=new UserListAdapter();
yurlistview.setAdapter(a);

Comment: seems like you don't know how to use "holder pattern" ... if convertView != null you do not setup views with values ...

Comment: thank you.actually I know this.but I confused here because of this I am facing issue.Now I fixed the issue.